# Update List on Click React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, render

The display of map function is updating on input change only. Can someone explain why.

Even though I m useEffect refreshing the page on stack change. Its not working. only input field change is updating the display.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [stack, setStack] = useState([]);
  const [values, setvalues] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Refeshed");
  }, [stack]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="app-left">
        <input
          className="stack-input"
          placeholder="Element"
          value={values}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setvalues(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <button
          className="push-btn"
          onClick={() => {
            stack.push(values);
          }}
        >
          Push
        </button>
        <button
          className="pop-btn"
          onClick={() => {
            stack.pop();
          }}
        >
          Pop
        </button>
      </div>
      <ul className="app-right">
        {stack.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your buttons aren't updating state.

Comment: I can do push and pop..it changing but the change is only showing when i update the input field

Comment: Changing state does a new render. You might be able to push things into stack but the `useEffect` won't recognise it because you're not using the `setStack` function as part of the process. You're updating an array but not changing state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call `setStack` on `click`, and use `prevState` to update values. Calling `setStack` with let `useEffect` to recognise the change in state and will re-render the component

```
setStack(oldStack => [...oldStack, values]); // adding (.push)
```

To pop

```
setItems(oldStack => oldStack.slice(0, -1)); // removes last element
```

Answer (score 0):

That is because React uses shallow comparison when the state changes to take the decision to rerender or not. You always updated the existing array and that avoids rerendering. You need to create a new array for each operation (push or pop).

Following would also work

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

function App() {
  const [stack, setStack] = useState([]);
  const [values, setvalues] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    // console.log("Refeshed");
  }, [stack]);

  const push = (value) => {
    setStack((prevStack) => [...prevStack, value]);
  };

  const pop = () => {
    setStack((prevStack) => prevStack.slice(0, prevStack.length - 1));
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="app-left">
        <input
          className="stack-input"
          placeholder="Element"
          value={values}
          onChange={(e) => {
            setvalues(e.target.value);
          }}
        />
        <button
          className="push-btn"
          onClick={() => {
            push(values);
          }}
        >
          Push
        </button>
        <button
          className="pop-btn"
          onClick={() => {
            pop();
          }}
        >
          Pop
        </button>
      </div>
      <ul className="app-right">
        {stack.map((item, index) => (
          <li key={index}>{item}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```